# How to find elements in puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm having trouble finding the exact element 'closeIcon' Please take a look if you have time and let me know what you think.

```
const PAGEURL = "https://www.shoepalace.com/";

try {
    
(async () => {


    
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});

    const page = await browser.newPage();  

    await page.goto(PAGEURL);
    
    page.waitForNavigation();
    
    const cancel = await page.waitForSelector('#cancelicon', {timeout: 60000});

    
    cancel.click();
    
    
    
})();
    
} catch (err){
    console.error(err);

}


function sleep(seconds) 
{
  var e = new Date().getTime() + (seconds * 1000);
  while (new Date().getTime() <= e) {}
}
```

Here is a ss of the page elements:

https://gyazo.com/f3ba9895dfb79f224119acfbdc7901bb

Here is the error in console:

https://gyazo.com/9a15f0e86f1c253182da89358f3de4b0

Comment: also to not the sleep function is not used i meant to delete that. It was only to test something breifly.

Comment: Are you sure the element you are trying to find is present in DOM? By looking at the image you attached it looks like the icon appears on an Iframe. You can not select the Iframe element directly you first need to get the frame content using contentFrame(), then inside frame content, you can select the element you are looking for.

Comment: From the screenshot, it looks the `closeIcon` is in an iframe.  You can't find things in an iframe by searching in the parent document.  You have to get the right iframe and search in its document.

Answer (score 1):

The element you're looking for is located into an iframe.

Each of the iframe is a different frame of the page, you usually don't see it but for exmaple when you call :

```
page.waitForSelector('#cancelicon', {timeout: 60000});
```

In reality you call :

```
page.mainFrame().waitForSelector('#cancelicon', {timeout: 60000});
```

So you need to select the correct frame which ocntains your selector.

If it can help I coded this quick-and-dirty way to have the frame associated to the selector (-1 if nothing found, 0 for the main frame and a number for the corresponding frame) :

```
async function getFrameAssociatedToSelector(page, selector){
  if (selector !== ''){
    let querySelectoronPage = await page.$(selector);
    if(querySelectoronPage === null){
      for(var i=0;i<page.mainFrame().childFrames().length;i++){
        let querySelectoronFrame = await page.mainFrame().childFrames()[i].$(selector);
        if(querySelectoronFrame === null){
          continue;
        }else{
          return i+1;
        };
      };
      return -1;
    }else{
      return 0;
    }
  }else{
    return -1;
  };
};
```

You can then use it this way :

```
    if(stepFrame === 0){
      page.waitForSelector('#cancelicon', {timeout: 60000});
    }else{
      page.mainFrame().childFrames()[stepFrame-1].waitForSelector('#cancelicon', {timeout: 60000});
    };
```